# select2 multi option select all box is giving a TypeError

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a multi option select2 box and wanted to add the ability to select all options. I found the following example [example link to js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/tjvjytp3/). However for me when I select the "select all" button nothing happens. When I look at the web console I see the following error shown below.

```
TypeError: a is undefined[Learn More] select2.min.js:1:31982
```

This appears to be some sort of select2 API problem that is not working in my browser environment. Not sure how to resolve this

## here is the file it is pointing to

```
// here is that line 1 from the file select2.min.js
/*! Select2 4.0.4 | https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/LICENSE.md */!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=function(b,c)
```

Comment: jsfiddle link that you share is working fine. Can you share your code so have a better idea.

Comment: Actually I just solved my issue. I am using flask and I have a layout that has all the API's that get rendered for all the HTML pagers. In my layout page I found out that I am using the following line <!-- <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> --> which is conflicting with the select2 option.

Comment: Thanks for effort. I appreciate your time. This was killing me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was related to loading two different version of JQuery.

I am using flask so I have a layout.html file that had both of these version of JQuery being loaded. After removing the bottom one the issue went away.

```
 <!-- Adding JQuery library  -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

   <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```